# Gatling not processing expressions in xml request body

Tags: gatling

Gatling version:

```
<gatling.version>3.4.2</gatling.version>
```

Scala Version: `2.12.12`

I have this expression in my xml file

`<item:seller-email>"${mobileUsername}"</item:seller-email>`

As per my understanding, the code below should replace the expression with actual value

`.body(RawFileBody("bodies/sample-item.xml"))`

However, it looks like Gatling is passing it as it is

`<item:seller-email>"${mobileUsername}"</item:seller-email>`

Any pointers on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is wrong, please have a look at the [documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/http_request/#request-body):

> RawFileBody lets you pass a raw file that will be sent as is.

> ElFileBody where path is the location of a file whose content will be parsed and resolved with Gatling EL engine